# How to use a text (string) to depict no relationship between tables from Oracle to HTML?

Tags: html, oracle

I am getting data from an Oracle database into an HTML table, I am replacing nulls with strings but I am just wondering if there is a way to add a string into html such as 'Unavailable' where there is no relationship

NB: PLACENAME_ID is a foreign key in the OWNER table

```
place = """ SELECT coalesce(NAME,'Unknown') FROM PLACES  WHERE PLACENAME_ID = """ + str(pid)
ownerquery = """ SELECT NAME, FROM OWNER WHERE PLACENAME_ID = """ + str(pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second query is invalid; comma between NAME and FROM?

Anyway: what you described sounds like **outer join** which enables you to display "something" when there's "nothing". Here's an example, based on Scott's schema:

There are 4 departments. Pay attention to department DEPTNO = 40, as there are no employees that work there:

```
SQL> select * from dept where deptno = 40;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select count(*) from emp where deptno = 40;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

In order to display it as well (when joined to the EMP table), you'd use outer join:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          WARD
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE
        40 OPERATIONS                   --> this!

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

If there was no outer join, you wouldn't even see the last row.

Now, how to implement that to your code, I wouldn't know - it doesn't even have any kind of a join, but it *should* as you mentioned a "foreign key". We don't have that tables' description either.